# Get the ID of a row that was just inserted

Tags: php, mysql

Supposing I am inserting a row into a table in MySql by php code, and my table has an ID which is not given but it is auto_increment - how can I retrieve the ID of the row I just inserted? 
My query in php looks like this:

```
$query = "insert into " . $this->tabel . " values (false,";
```

And after this I am filling the query with the values given as parameters in my function.
However, I need to update an internal variable of my php class with the current ID. How can I obtain it?

Thank you

```
public function insert ($keyValueSet) {

    $query = "insert into " . $this->tabel . " values (false,";
    $connection = new mysqli(ADDRESS, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DB);
    $cols = $this->getTableDesc();
    // $query construction ......
    $result = $connection->query($query);
    echo "ID: " . mysql_insert_id ();
    if ($result != 1)
        echo "Exception";
    $connection->close();
}
```

The incremented field is the first field (where i say: values (false,) and MySql does auto-increment this field, as I saw in the database.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+get+the+last+inserted+ID%3F+mysql+php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the default `mysql_connect()`

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```

For procedural MySQLi e.g `mysqli_connect()`

```
$id = mysqli_insert_id();
```

For Object Oriented MySQLi e.g. `$db = new mysqli()`

```
$id = $db->insertid; // replace $db with your DB variable name
```

Comment: thank you... it is exactly as you pointed. i was trying to use mysql while previously i had mysqli .

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_insert_id()`

[PHP Manual on MySql Insert ID](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Can you show the code you're using to make the insert? PHP doc says a 0 is returned if the previous query does not return an auto increment value. This could happen in two cases:

- Your last query was not an `INSERT`
- Your table does not, in fact, have an auto increment field.

Comment: it does not work... it shows me ID=0, while in the DB it inserted with ID=14

Answer (score 1):

[`mysql_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) normally but if you are using PDO then [`PDO::lastInsertId`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)